# Hibernate 2 records being inserted for Single JAVA Object

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate Implementation of JPA with Spring.

```
 Class Country{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<State> stateList;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Current_State_ID")
    State currnetState;

    }

Class State{
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Country_ID")
private Country country;

}


    State stateObj = new State();
    country.getStateList().add(stateObj);

    country.setCurrnetState(stateObj);
    countryRepository.saveAndFlush(country);
```

countryRepository is a JPA Repository Implemenntation.
This creates 2 entries for in State Table, which messes up my logic. Can someone please point me what I am doing worng.

Comment: Please share more details for us to help....Did u try setting the show_sql property to true and monitored the sql queries being generated?

Comment: Yes it does make 2 inserts to State Table.
Also this is just a small identical snippet of code. Actual table has many more columns and different usage.

Comment: and where is the persistence code? you know, where you call em.persist, and what state are objects in when passed in, etc

Comment: You have a bidirectionnal link so we need the other part of the link: mapping in State class to see if link is done correctly.

Comment: Oh Yes I forgot that. I have updated the question. its something like counrtyRepository.saveAndFlush(country);

Comment: State needs its reference to Country set, but I don't believe that is part of this issue.  You will have to show what your saveAndFlush method is doing, and how you are obtaining the context within it - make sure it is empty or picking up a state object from elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but changing my code to following works for me.

```
List<State> stateList = new ArrayList<State>();
stateList.add(state);

country.setStateList(stateList);
```

Creating a New List instance and setting it to country.